# Find submatrix that maximizes value of elements within a given matrix

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a square integer matrix of size n x n, find the square sub-matrix which contains the largest value of elements of all possible sub-matrices, including the original n x n matrix.

Additional details:

- There is an obvious case where all integers are >0 where the answer is the original matrix. This question only gets interesting when you have a matrix containing negative numbers.
- The brute force solution is O(n^3). It involves computing the value of all possible submatrices.
- The optimum solution is O(n^2). I do not know how to reach this solution, but I have been told it exists.

Comments:

I encountered this question in an interview recently. It was the first and only time an interview question has totally stumped me.

There are sort of similar problems that involve DP, but I haven't been able to map their solutions to this problem in any meaningful way.

Comment: Start with one-dimensional array and extend answer to 2d

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085737/find-sum-of-largest-subset-of-array/43086264#43086264

Comment: Possibly related http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/cats02.pdf